# Splash screens takes forever to load while showing interstitial ad in flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, splash-screen

I am trying to add an interstitial ad that displays after the splash but I am struggling a bit. Some times the code perfectly, but sometimes the splash screen takes forever to load and the screen does not move forward. What to do? I tried to add the timer of 12 seconds but the play console rejected it.What to do?
Here is my code:

`````
class Splashscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splashscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Splashscreen> createState() => _SplashscreenState();
}

class _SplashscreenState extends State<Splashscreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      _createInterstitialAd();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _interstitialAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
  int _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
  int maxFailedLoadAttempts = 3;

  void _createInterstitialAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: '***********************',
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          _interstitialAd = ad;
          _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
          _showInterstitialAd();
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          _numInterstitialLoadAttempts += 1;
          _interstitialAd = null;
          if (_numInterstitialLoadAttempts < maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
            _createInterstitialAd();
          } else {
            _navigateToTabBarr();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showInterstitialAd() {
    if (_interstitialAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show interstitial before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _interstitialAd!.show();
    _interstitialAd = null;
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TabBarr()),
    );
  }


  void _navigateToTabBarr() {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TabBarr()),
          (route) => false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.orange],
          ),
        ),
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * 0.3,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/title.png',
                      width: size.width * 0.5,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.2),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: size.height * 0.1,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SpinKitSpinningLines(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: size.width * 0.2,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    const Text(
                      'Ad is Loading...',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}````
`````

Comment: This isn't a viable solution. Ad loads can take time depending on the network, inventory, bidding, mediation waterfalls, etc. You should probably use a timer to see if certain amount has passed when loading the Ad. Longer time than 3 sec. on a splashscreen is a bad ux. You should try to load the ad in the said time, if loaded show the ad, if not then navigate to `TabBarr`.